# Java "guessing number" game

Tags: java

First, sorry, when I dont have the best English, its not my first language..

So, to the problem.. Ive got an exercise, that i have to develope a minigame, in which I have to think for a number between 1 and 1024. The program then have to ask if a number is littler, greater than or equal to the number, the user thinks of. But the computer is only allowed to ask 10 questions. However. I dont know, how to do this and i already did it for the last few days. I also didnt find anything for it in the internet. 
Here is the Code i have till yet:

```java
package numberguessing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numberguessing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int av = 0;
        int rz;
        System.out.println("Please think for a number between 1 and 1024");

        //  1   2   3    4    5    6     7     8     9      10
        // 2   4   8   16   32   64   128   256   512   1024


        System.out.println("I will know your number after max 10 questions");
        System.out.println("I will name you a number");
        System.out.println("You have to say, if the number is littler, greater than or equal to your number");

        rz = a/2 ;
        System.out.println("Is your number littler, greater than or equal to " + rz +"?");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String an = sc.next();


        do{
            av++;
            if(an.equalsIgnoreCase("littler")) {
                rz = rz / 2 ;
                System.out.println("Is your number littler, greater than or equal to " + rz +"?");
                an = sc.next();
            } else if(an.equalsIgnoreCase("greater")){
                rz =  (rz + 1024) / 2 ;
                System.out.println("Is your number littler, greater than or equal to " + rz +"?");
                an  = sc.next();
            }  else if(an.equalsIgnoreCase("equal")) {
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: The answer wasnt littler, greater or equal");
        }} while(!an.equalsIgnoreCase("equal"));


        System.out.println("I won the game after " + av + " tries");


        sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: rz = a/2 ; where is your variable 'a' defined

Comment: Are you getting compilation errors? Can you provide sample input and output of the tests you've written?

Comment: oh. In my code is it defined, but I think i deleted it while i translated the text in english :) The a is for 1024

Comment: @Freiheit (cooler Name übrigens) no i dont get compilation errors.. And yes..  Is your number littler, greater than or equal to 512?
littler
Is your number littler, greater than or equal to 256?
littler
Is your number littler, greater than or equal to 128?
greater
Is your number littler, greater than or equal to 576?
equal
I won the game after 3 tries

Comment: Try to do it on paper. For simplicity use numbers between 1 and 16. Lets say that my number is 9. What steps would you need to take? Does your code follow these steps? Does these steps work also for other numbers like 5?

Comment: @Pshemo
My Code has the problem, theres like the number is greater than 8 but lesser than 12, it could get back higher than 12 or lesser than 8

On paper these steps
(Middle between 1 and 16) 8 - greater
(middle between 8 and 16) 12 - lesser
(middle betweeen 8 and 12) 10 - lesser
(middle between 9 and 9) 9 - equals

Comment: So as you see you want to calculate middle value of some range. How many numbers represent range? Do you have them in your code? How can they be calculated?

Comment: Also you skipped few steps for `10 - lesser (middle between 9 and 9)`. How did you get those`9 and 9`?

Comment: @Pshemo for the Also you skipped few steps for 10 - lesser (middle between 9 and 9). How did you get those 9 and 9?... The number was lesser than 10 and higher than 8- theres only 1 possible number than.. For the other questions,  I dont understand your first question, sorry (Sorry im a bit tired, :D)

Comment: So you assumed that values represented by that range can't be an answer. It could be true here but what if number I picked is `16`? I will end up with ranges `1-16` -> `8-16` -> `12-16` -> `14-16` so now your assumption would suggest that answer must be 15...

Comment: In my first question I tried to suggest that in your loop you are only updating `rz` variable which can represent only one end of range of possible solutions. But what about other end of range? Should it be always 1 or 1024?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) and [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to perhaps make it a little easier to follow:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numberguessing {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please think for a number between 1 and 1024 inclusive");
    System.out.println("I will know your number after max 10 questions!");
    System.out.println("I will guess your number!");
    System.out.println("After each guess, respond with littler, greater, or equal depending on my guess.");
    int result = Collections.binarySearch(new AbstractList<Integer>() {
      private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      public int size() { return 1025; }
      public Integer get(int i) {
        System.out.printf("My guess is: %d. Is it littler, greater, or equal? ", 0 + i);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        assert s.length() > 0;
        switch (s.toLowerCase()) {
          case "greater":
            return -1;
          case "littler":
            return 1;
          case "equal":
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
      }
    }, 0);

    if (result < 0) {
      System.out.println("That is impossible.");
    } else {
      System.out.printf("Your number is %d.\n", result);
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/GNLP/2)

**Example usage where I choose to guess 513:**

```
Please think for a number between 1 and 1024 inclusive
I will know your number after max 10 questions!
I will guess your number!
After each guess, respond with littler, greater, or equal depending on my guess.
My guess is: 512. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  greater
My guess is: 768. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  Littler
My guess is: 640. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  littler
My guess is: 576. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  littler
My guess is: 544. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  littler
My guess is: 528. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  littler
My guess is: 520. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  littler
My guess is: 516. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  littler
My guess is: 514. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  littler
My guess is: 513. Is it littler, greater, or equal?  EQUAL
Your number is 513.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I answer littler, i get a littler question, if I anwer greater, i get a littler number :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I never use the word "littler" since it is grammatically incorrect so my brain got confused... it should work now...

Comment: `Littler` is not a real word, you are using  it as a comparative of `little`, which also would be inappropriate. Lesser would make sense but again not be a great choice. I personally would user `lower`, `higher`, and `equal` for the possible input or even better just use `l` , `h`, and `e` instead so it is easier for the user and they are less likely to make a mistake (compare character in this case)